# Swift / LaunchScreen background

Tags: ios, swift

I use an UIView extension to set the background in my app.

```
import UIKit

extension UIView {
    func addBackground() {
        // screen width and height:
        let width = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
        let height = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height

        let imageViewBackground = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height))
        imageViewBackground.image = UIImage(named: "index_clear")
        imageViewBackground.clipsToBounds = true

        // you can change the content mode:
        imageViewBackground.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
        self.addSubview(imageViewBackground)
        self.sendSubviewToBack(imageViewBackground)
    }}
```

The picture is 3-4x larger than an iphone screen.
Now I'm trying to set the same background in the LaunchScreen. At the same position.

I've tryed to perform that with an Image View within the Interface Builder, but even if I choose "Aspect Fill", the pictures aren't at the same position.

Any idea? Help is very appreciated.

Screenshots as requested

LaunchScreen:

[image]

Every other Screen:

[image]

@DeyaEldeen's suggestion

[image]

Comment: please add two screenshots so we become sure we can help you exactly as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change is caused by navigation bar height

try setting the background like this in a view controller

```
let imageViewBackground = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height))
imageViewBackground.image = UIImage(named: "index_clear")
imageViewBackground.center = self.view.center
self.view.addSubview(imageViewBackground)
```

Comment: I've editited the post with a screen for your solution. That didn't nearly did the job

Comment: how are you adding the background for the splash? do you use constraints? what are the constraints if any?

Comment: I only use center X and center Y

Comment: OK, the only thing I can help with is telling you how I matched the (background of the splash and the next view that appears after the splash) in my last 2 apps I developed, the splash background image view had a constraint to have the same dimensions of the screen, then in the next view the background image would have the same constraint with having the navigation bar offset compensated, this gave me the result of looking like they were the same image without noticing any difference,I hope this helps.

Comment: thank you so far. hope there's a bit more I can do since I'm totally satisfied with my extension.

Comment: by the way, one thing you can do is (disable launch screen for the app, yes you can do that) and make the initial screen a usual view controller with a background built by the extension along with labels and such.